# Was the Sabbath in force at the time of Abraham?

Tags: sabbath, ten-commandments, the-law

Those Christians who observe Saturday as the Sabbath often claim that when God rested on the seventh day he sanctified it and set it apart for holy use.

Genesis 2:1-3

> <sup>**1**</sup> Thus the heavens and the earth were finished, and all the host of them. <sup>**2**</sup> And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made. <sup>**3**</sup> And God blessed the seventh day, and sanctified it: because that in it he had rested from all his work which God created and made.

They claimed God blessed the seventh day while he was resting on it and not created centuries later when the children of Israel departed Egypt. He sanctified it (setting it apart for holy use). Sabbath keepers claim the Sabbath was in existence from the end of creation week to the time of Moses when the Law was revealed to the children of Israel.

They back this up by quoting Genesis 26:3-5.

Jehovah is talking to Abraham and says the following:

> <sup>**3**</sup> Sojourn in this land, and I will be with thee, and will bless thee; for unto thee, and unto thy seed, I will give all these countries, and I will perform the oath which I sware unto Abraham thy father; <sup>**4**</sup> And I will make thy seed to multiply as the stars of heaven, and will give unto thy seed all these countries; and in thy seed shall all the nations of the earth be blessed; <sup>**5**</sup> Because that Abraham obeyed my voice, and kept my charge, my *commandments*, my statutes, and my laws.

Sabbath observers claim that when the children of Israel in Egypt became slaves they could no longer observe the Sabbath so after 400 years of slavery in Egypt the Sabbath became "lost". After the departure from Egypt God had to reveal to the Israelites the Sabbath because they had no knowledge of the Sabbath. It didn't mean that the revealing of the Sabbath was the first time it had ever been given unto man.

Exodus 16:1-5

> <sup>**1**</sup> And they took their journey from Elim, and all the congregation of the children of Israel came unto the wilderness of Sin, which is between Elim and Sinai, on the fifteenth day of the second month after their departing out of the land of Egypt. <sup>**2**</sup> And the whole congregation of the children of Israel murmured against Moses and Aaron in the wilderness: <sup>**3**</sup> And the children of Israel said unto them, Would to God we had died by the hand of the Lord in the land of Egypt, when we sat by the flesh pots, and when we did eat bread to the full; for ye have brought us forth into this wilderness, to kill this whole assembly with hunger. <sup>**4**</sup> Then said the Lord unto Moses, Behold, I will rain bread from heaven for you; and the people shall go out and gather a certain rate every day, that I may prove them, whether they will walk in my law, or no. <sup>**5**</sup> And it shall come to pass, that on the sixth day, they shall prepare that which they bring in, and it shall be twice as much as they gather daily.

At this point, Jehovah is preparing the Israelites to begin keeping the Sabbath, something that had not been done for 400 years, if those who honor the Sabbath are correct.

Exodus 16:22-30

> <sup>**22**</sup> And it came to pass, that on the sixth day they gathered twice as much bread, two omers for one man: and all the rulers of the congregation came and told Moses. <sup>**23**</sup> And he said unto them, This is that which the Lord hath said, Tomorrow is the rest of the holy sabbath unto the Lord: bake that which ye will bake to day, and seethe that ye will seethe; and that which remaineth over lay up for you to be kept until the morning. <sup>**24**</sup> And they laid it up till the morning, as Moses bade: and it did not stink, neither was there any worm therein. <sup>**25**</sup> And Moses said, Eat that to day; for to day is a sabbath unto the Lord: to day ye shall not find it in the field. <sup>**26**</sup> Six days ye shall gather it; but on the seventh day, which is the sabbath, in it there shall be none.
>
> <sup>**27**</sup> And it came to pass, that there went out some of the people on the seventh day for to gather, and they found none. <sup>**28**</sup> And the Lord said unto Moses, How long refuse ye to keep my commandments and my laws? <sup>**29**</sup> See, for that the Lord hath given you the sabbath, therefore he giveth you on the sixth day the bread of two days; abide ye every man in his place, let no man go out of his place on the seventh day. <sup>**30**</sup> So the people rested on the seventh day.

And so began the Jews keeping the Sabbath which they continue to do to this day. It is important to note that the Sabbath predated the giving of the 10 Commandments in Exodus 20.

Jesus kept the Sabbath in the New Testament times. He also made the well-known statement in Mark 2:23-28

> <sup>**23**</sup> And it came to pass, that he went through the corn fields on the sabbath day; and his disciples began, as they went, to pluck the ears of corn. <sup>**24**</sup> And the Pharisees said unto him, Behold, why do they on the sabbath day that which is not lawful? <sup>**25**</sup> And he said unto them, Have ye never read what David did, when he had need, and was an hungred, he, and they that were with him? <sup>**26**</sup> How he went into the house of God in the days of Abiathar the high priest, and did eat the shewbread, which is not lawful to eat but for the priests, and gave also to them which were with him? <sup>**27**</sup> And he said unto them, The sabbath was made for man, and not man for the sabbath: <sup>**28**</sup> Therefore the Son of man is Lord also of the sabbath.

This is crucial. Jesus did not say the Sabbath was made for the Jew, but it was made for man. In the Greek text the word "man" meant human or mankind, or so I have been told, by Sabbath keepers of course.

Some say that of all the ten commandments that were given in Exodus 20 only nine are repeated in the New Testament and the only one that is not mentioned is the Sabbath. However, of all the commandments given in the Torah several are not mentioned in the New Testament as well, including the law against bestiality. Does that mean bestiality is not a sin in New Testament times?

There was no need to repeat the Sabbath commandment in the New Testament because the whole country of Israel not only kept the Sabbath but there were so many extra man-made laws making the Sabbath a burden Jesus had to show everyone the Pharisees and Sadducees were too zealous in their effort for the Sabbath not to be broken.

Jesus was once asked the following:

Matthew 19:16, 17

> <sup>**16**</sup> And, behold, one came and said unto him, Good Master, what good thing shall I do, that I may have eternal life? <sup>**17**</sup> And he said unto him, Why callest thou me good? there is none good but one, that is, God: but if thou wilt enter into life, keep the commandments.

Notice Jesus said if one would want to enter into eternal life, he should keep the commandments. He was asked which ones and Jesus stated a few of the commandments encoded into the ten commandments given at Mount Sinai.

I am trying to be as fair as I can for those who observe the Sabbath but does Genesis 26:5 prove that Abraham kept the (ten) Commandments? Why are why not?

> Because that Abraham obeyed my voice, and kept my charge, my commandments, my statutes, and my laws.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth I am interested on your take on this question. I know you have a lot of knowledge about keeping the Sabbath.

Comment: Consider that by saying „do not care about the tomorrow“ Jesus declares every day a holy day for the search of heavenly kingdom. And he said „before Abraham I am“, so in this context  your analysis may have to be extended.

Comment: I question your use of the term "Sabbatarians".  It makes us Sabbath keepers sound like a bunch of weirdos or something.  "Commandment keepers" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @controlvoice You're right. I looked up the definition of Sabbatarian online and it actually means someone who observes Sunday as the Sabbath so I will have to redo my whole question. Did you find my description of Sabbath (Saturday) keepers fair?

Comment: @controlvoice I have removed "Sabbatarian" from my question. Thanks for confronting me about my misuse of the word Sabbatarian.

Comment: Do not make unnecessary edits in order to bump your posts, and don't put your name in the question body like that. Your name is already clearly shown at the bottom of the post!

Comment: @SaberTruthTiger--Sabbatarian means someone who keeps Sunday?  Whoa, whoa, whoa!  You sure about that?  Never heard that one before.  If that is true then I was confusing Sabbatarian with Sabbath keeper.  I changed my name to moron to show my humility.

Comment: Us Sabbath keepers are a weird bunch, we got all kinds of crazy ideas.  I'm as crazy as it gets, won't go to a restaurant on Saturday.  And I'm not even Jewish.  That crazy or what?

Comment: @moron Sabbatarian is one who observes Sunday as if it is the Sabbath https://www.google.com/search?q=sabbatarian&oq=S&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39i650l2j46i131i433i650j46i199i433i465i512j46i340i512l2j46i199i340i433i465i512j46i131i199i433i465i512j0i271.2188722381j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4):

There are two aspects to this question:

1. "**Commandments**"

The words used to describe "commandments" can apply to any of God's instructions including the 10 commandments.  However, the record in Genesis makes it obvious that all 10 of the commandments listed in Ex 20 were in force well before their formal declaration at Sinai - see appendix below.

I note that in that survey, the Sabbath command is the only one explicitly stated.

2. **Other Words in Gen 26:5**

There are several words used to imply commands or divine requirements in Gen 26:5 that Abraham is said to have kept:

- מִשְׁמֶרֶת (mishmereth) = "charge" is used to describe the keeping of Passover (Ex 12:6, 16:23; the keeping of things associated with the Ark of the Covenant (Ex 16:32, 34, Num 3:31) and the tabernacle (Ex 8:35, Num 1:53, 3:7, 8, 25, 28, 38); keeping the holy commands of the Lord generally (Ex 18:30, Lev 22:9), etc.  Thus, the word is generally applied to cultic requirements such as the sacrificial system that Abraham practiced.
- מִצְוָה (mitvah) = "commandment" is used of direct instructions to God's people such as the 10 commandments themselves (Ex 20:6, 24:12); breaking these commandments is sinful (Lev 4:2, 13) including ceremonial practices.
- חֻקָּה (chuqqah) = "statute" is used to describe mostly ritual laws, Ex 13:10, 12:4, 43, etc.  Again, this would, in the case of Abraham presumably apply to his practice of building altars wherever he camped.
- תּוֹרָה (torah) = "direction, instruction, law" is used to describe the law of the 10 commandments (Ex 24:12) as well as ritual sacrificial laws (Lev 6:9, 14, 25, 7:1), etc.

Thus, we have numerous laws that were observed before Sinai such as:

- the 10 commandments (see appendix below)
- a few of the sacrificial laws as evidenced by the story of Cain and Abel, Noah (when he existed the Ark), and the Abraham
- the law of not eating blood in meat (Gen 9:4, 5)

Thus, it appears that whatever one says about the Sabbath command before Sinai also applies to a number of other laws as well.  Now, which apply after the Resurrection of Christ is a completely separate question.

Lastly, concerning NT commands of God, the NT contains much more than the 10 commandments - by the count of an an-named wit, the NT contains about 1050 commands of God (See https://www.abc.net.au/reslib/201407/r1308729_17984331.pdf  and  https://www.cai.org/bible-studies/1050-new-testament-commands  and  https://www.facebook.com/notes/the-real-truth-movement/the-1050-new-testament-commandmentslaws/690826194404882/  and  http://www.wholebible.com/NT_commandments.htm  and  http://www.biblicalresearchreports.com/gods-commands-in-the-new-testament/ )

Included in this impressive list is the Sabbath command in places like The "Sabbath was made for man, not man for the Sabbath.  So the Son of Man is Lord even of the Sabbath." Mark 2:27, 28.  "On the Sabbath day we went out of the city to the riverside, where prayer was customarily made." Acts 16:13. "On the next Sabbath almost the whole city gathered to hear the word of the Lord." Acts 13:44.  See also Acts 13:27, 42, 15:21, 17:2, 18:4.  However, included here we might also include the command to not eat blood such as Acts 15:29.

Thus, Gen 26:5 indicates that Abraham kept all the divine commands known to him at the time which presumably included all those listed above, namely:

- the 10 commandments (see appendix below)
- a few of the sacrificial laws as evidenced by the story of Cain and Abel, Noah (when he existed the Ark), and the Abraham
- the law of not eating blood in meat (Gen 9:4, 5)

**APPENDIX - 10 Commandments before Sinai**

**Commandment #1 – Worship only YHWH**:

- Gen 22:5, 24:26, 48, 52 all describe worship of the true God of heaven, YHWH.
- Gen 35:1-4 – Jacob instructs his whole household to eliminate all foreign gods

**Commandment #2 – Idolatry prohibited**

- Gen 31:32-35 – Jacob clearly understood that idolatry was forbidden.
- Gen 35:1-4 – Jacob instructs his whole household to eliminate all foreign gods

**Commandment #3 –Cursing and taking the name of the LORD in vain prohibited**

- Job 1:5 – When these celebrations ended—sometimes after several days—Job would purify his children. He would get up early in the morning and offer a burnt offering for each of them. For Job said to himself, “Perhaps my children have sinned and have cursed God in their hearts.” This was Job’s regular practice.

**Commandment #4 – Sabbath worship**

- Gen 2:1-3 – Thus the heavens and the earth were completed in all their vast array.  And by the seventh day God had finished the work He had been doing; so on that day He rested from all His work.  Then God blessed the seventh day and sanctified it, because on that day He rested from all the work of creation that He had accomplished.
- Ex 5:5 - And Pharaoh said, “Behold, the people of the land are now many, and you make them rest [שָׁבַת shabath] from their burdens!”
- Ex 16 also records the incident with manna and that collecting manna on the seventh-day Sabbath was forbidden

**Commandment #5 – Respect for parents, elders and authority**

- Gen 28:6, 7 tells of the story of Jacob following his mother’s advice.  Respect for parents is built into the very fabric of the patriarchal stories in Genesis.

**Commandment #6 – Sanctity of Human life**

- Gen 4:8-12, 15 records Cain’s punishment for the sin of murder
- Gen 4:23, 24 – Lamech realizes that he has murdered someone and will suffer consequences
- Gen 9:5, 6 records that murder was prohibited under the ancient Noahide covenant

**Commandment #7 – Adultery prohibited**

- Gen 12:10-20, 20:1-17, 26:6-11 all record “adultery narratives” in which the patriarch is (correctly) chided for almost tricking a pagan king into committing adultery
- Gen 19 records the appalling events involving attempted pack-rape of the two angels
- Gen 39:7-9 – Joseph calls Potiphar’s wife proposal “a great evil and sin against God”.
- Gen 49:4 – Reuben is scalded for his sin of incest
- Gen 34 – the story of Dinah records a heinous incident involving her defilement (plus murder and lying)

**Commandment #8 – Stealing prohibited and respect for property**

- Gen 30:33 – Laban and Jacob discuss the problem of stealing of wages and property
- Gen 31:32-35 – Laban is angry about the sin of stealing the household gods
- Gen 44:9 – Joseph’s brother accused of stealing his divination cup.

**Commandment #9 – Lying prohibited; insistence of honesty and integrity**

- Gen 4 – the story of Cain being punished, among other things for not being honest with Abel and God in his statements
- Gen 12:10-20, 20:1-17, 26:6-11 all record “adultery narratives” in which the patriarch is (correctly) chided for lying to a pagan king about their marital status
- In the story of Jacob, he is pejoratively called Jacob = “deceiver”, Gen 27:36.
- Gen 37:31-33 – Jacob rebuked for lying and deception

**Commandment #10 – Coveting prohibited**

- Gen 3:6 – the woman is tricked by the serpent using the sin of covetousness
- Job 31:9, 10 – Job says he is innocent of coveting his Neighbour’s wife.

Comment: does "cultic requirements" mean? Every time I read something like that I think of "cult" or Jim Jones, the Mormons, the Jehovah's Witnesses, etc. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: I have to edit my original question because you mentioned that the Sabbath was first revealed to Israel in Ezodus 16 and not Ezodus 20. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I knew that for years throughout the 70s and 80s but when I wrote my question I had forgotten that important fact. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I was wrong. I DID indeed mention the Sabbath was revealed in Exodus 16. But many people still believe the Sabbath was not given until the ten commandments.

Comment: @SaberTruthTiger - I am using "cultic requirements" and "cultic practice" in the technical sense of organized ritual - the animal sacrifices is a good example.

Comment: Is there are reason why you think Abraham was not lying/deceiving when he told (or told Sarah to tell) the Pharaoh and later Abimelech was his sister rather than his wife?

Comment: @DanFefferman - Indeed, Abraham was lying about his wife as listed above.  I did not wish to imply anything else.  See under commandment #9 above, second dot point.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I added my upvote now.

Comment: "Thus, it appears that whatever one says about the Sabbath command before Sinai also applies to a number of other laws as well." Your answer seems to be, since other commands may be inferred to have been in place before Sinai, the Sabbath should be put in that same group. But I did not see any event which supports that inference and is not really evidence such a command was in place in **Abraham's** time. It is more like the Jews who believed that God gave Abraham all the Law, but the details of that happening were omitted from Genesis, so the Book of Jubilees "corrected" that oversight.

Comment: @RevelationLad - I was citing evidence that all the commandments existed before they were given in written at Sinaia. The Sabbath existed from creation.

Answer (score 1):

The Sabbath as the day of rest was not known to humanity before Exodus 16. The seventh day of a week is a picture. Just like all the other days and years of rest in the law of Moses. The Sabbath is not a day but a person. Jesus the Messiah, the rock of salvation, is the real Sabbath. We read about His shadow well before Exodus 16, in Genesis 28:10-19. The seventh day of Genesis 2 is not a day, either. It is a reality of the rest in and with God. Unlike the first six days, it has no end. The text does not say it follows the evening/morning pattern of the previous days. God rested from His work and Him alone. Humanity did not enter God's rest then.

That is why the author of Hebrews says:

*"Therefore, since the promise of entering his rest still stands, let us be careful that none of you be found to have fallen short of it.
For we also have had the good news proclaimed to us, just as they did; but the message they heard was of no value to them, because they did not share the faith of those who obeyed.
Now we who have believed enter that rest, just as God has said, “So I declared on oath in my anger, ‘They shall never enter my rest.’” And yet his works have been finished since the creation of the world.
For somewhere he has spoken about the seventh day in these words: “On the seventh day God rested from all his works.”
And again in the passage above he says, “They shall never enter my rest.”
Therefore since it still remains for some to enter that rest, and since those who formerly had the good news proclaimed to them did not go in because of their disobedience,
God again set a certain day, calling it “Today.” This he did when a long time later he spoke through David, as in the passage already quoted: “Today, if you hear his voice, do not harden your hearts.”
For if Joshua had given them rest, God would not have spoken later about another day.
There remains, then, a Sabbath-rest for the people of God;
for anyone who enters God’s rest also rests from their works, just as God did from his.
Let us, therefore, make every effort to enter that rest, so that no one will perish by following their example of disobedience."* **Hebrews 4:1-11**

Abraham did not know and did not keep the law of Moses (*"Nevertheless, death reigned from the time of Adam to the time of Moses, even over those who did not sin by breaking a command, as did Adam"* - **Romans 5:14**). He did not know the day of Sabbath/Saturday. His rest was in the promises of God/His Logos.

*"By faith he made his home in the promised land like a stranger in a foreign country; he lived in tents, as did Isaac and Jacob, who were heirs with him of the same promise.
For he was looking forward to the city with foundations, whose architect and builder is God.
And by faith even Sarah, who was past childbearing age, was enabled to bear children because she considered him faithful who had made the promise.
And so from this one man, and he as good as dead, came descendants as numerous as the stars in the sky and as countless as the sand on the seashore.
All these people were still living by faith when they died. They did not receive the things promised; they only saw them and welcomed them from a distance, admitting that they were foreigners and strangers on earth.
People who say such things show that they are looking for a country of their own.
If they had been thinking of the country they had left, they would have had opportunity to return.
Instead, they were longing for a better country—a heavenly one. Therefore God is not ashamed to be called their God, for he has prepared a city for them."* **Hebrews 11:9-16**

Answer (score 1):

I find myself agreeing almost to Dottard’s answer. It seems to be a well-studied answer. Further and in addition to his answer, I give below some more points:

It was Jesus Himself who gave me the first clue that Moses didn’t start everything in the Old Testament!

“Because of this Moses has given you circumcision; (**not** that it is **of Moses**, but **of the fathers**); and on a sabbath, you circumcise a man” (John 7:22)!!

Then it dawned on me that most of the commandments and ordinances were there among the very few saintly fathers! Following are some of such commands and statutes I found in the Old Testament:

***Sacrifices to God*** – Abel started it right at the beginning of human history in Genesis. (Some say, it was God who started it when He removed the “leaves of the fig tree” and “clothed” Adam and Eve with “coats of **skin**)

***Circumcision*** – It began with Abraham.

***Sabbath*** – Right at the Creation itself.

***Clean and unclean animals*** – Noah knew how to differentiate them. (Abel also knew it from Adam and Eve (Genesis 4:4).

***Idolatry was sin*** – Patriarch Jacob knew about it (Genesis 35:2)

***Killing is sin*** – Cain was warned well by God Himself (Genesis 4:7).

***Adultery is sin*** – Patriarch Joseph knew it was a sin against God. (It is remarkable that he didn’t say it was a sin against Potiphar!!!).

Then what about Mr. Moses?

He is the first person to record all of these in a codified single systematic source. Before Moses, God was dealing with only a few Patriarchs directly on a one-to-one basis. He gave them His “mishmereth”, “mitvah”, “chuqqah”, etc, (Genesis 26:5). It is through Moses that God began to act in a “mass”ive way!! He selected a nation itself!

**Sabbath before Moses**

In all probability, Adam and Eve – the first human family – who were created on the sixth day kept the Sabbath together with the Creator God!! (God had a habit of walking with them in the Garden in the evening and talking to them and imparting to them His holy laws and commandments!! (Genesis 3:8-9).

While I cannot emphatically prove beyond any doubt, I have seen enough clues to see that the Patriarchs kept the Sabbath!

Note:- It was God’s habit to start great things on the first day just like what happened in the Creation itself!

“For after **seven** more days I will cause it to rain on the earth forty days and forty nights (Gen 7:4). (God waited 7 more days to begin the Flood on the first day after the Sabbath?). “And it was after the **seven** days, the waters of the flood came into being on the earth” (Gen 7:10).

Like the Creator, like the creature!

“And he (Noah) waited yet another **seven** days, and again he sent forth the dove out of the ark” (Gen 8:10). (Why did Noah wait for seven days? Like his Creator Noah set out to work after the Sabbath). “And he waited another **seven** days, and sent forth the dove” (verse 12).

There are clues that other Patriarchs also knew the significance of seven. See Genesis 21:28; 29:18; 50:10 and others.

There was a moment in Jesus’ life when He, a physical Being, manifested Himself as a spiritual Being in the Transfiguration. The Scripture says that this happened “after **six** days” (Matt 17:1; Mark 9:2). Most probably, since Millennium is correlated to the seventh day, this Transfiguration happened on a Sabbath!

The same Being once when He existed in spiritual form manifested Himself in physical form to Abraham when Abraham “was sitting at the door of the tent in the heat of the day” by the oaks of the Mamre (Gen 18:1). Was it on a sabbath? We cannot be sure.

**Sabbath commandment in the New Testament**

I have read several times pastors and priests stating surely that of all the Ten Commandments, 9 are repeated in the New Testament as commands but only the Sabbath command is absent in the NT.

This is not true!

“So, then, there remains a sabbath rest to the people of God” (Heb 4:9).

(This verse is connected to verse 4: “For He has spoken somewhere about the seventh day this way, "And God rested from all His works in the seventh day.")

What is significant, here, is that throughout the 4th chapter, the author is talking about rest as a “figurative” thing for the Christian followers. But he uses “catapausis” as the Greek word for rest. Only in verse 9, he uses a different word, “sabbatismos”!!

Now “ismos” may mean a practice. I learned that the English “ism” (like in Mormonism) comes from this Greek word. In the Bible itself we have “Baptismos”, “Hagnismos” etc.

So according to Hebrews 4:9, a Sabbath practice remains for the people of God in the New Testament.

**Paul and Sabbath**

Paul is assumed to be against the Law including the Sabbath. But practically, Paul behaves in a law-abiding way.

“Now concerning the collection for the saints: as I directed the churches of Galatia, so you also are to do. On the **first day of every week**, each of you is to put something aside and store it up, as he may prosper, so that there will be no collecting when I come” (1 Cor 1-2).

Like the Creator God and like Noah, we see Paul also advising the believers to **rest** on the Sabbath and start **working** on the first day after the Sabbath!!

Answer (score 0):

Deuteronomy 5:3  The ten commandments , the covenant,  was not made with their fathers; Abraham,  Isaac  and Jacob but only with those people alive in that day.  The physical rest is a shadow of the rest we have in Christ. Jesus fulfilled the law with Godly love not by the works of the law. The true sabbath is your entire life in Christ resting from trying to be righteous by the law but in the righteousness of God by faith the law did not have. Galatians 3:12-14  The law had no righteousness,  justification,  mercy or forgiveness.  Hebrews 10:28.  If you are a law man you are a dead man.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/50548)

Comment: The old covenant was to make Israel a special nation “above all the nations” (Exo 19:5) which could not have been made with the fathers who were individuals! A shadow that leads to the real body comes only in light. In utter darkness, there cannot be any shadow. After all, God is going to judge ALL “according to their works” (Rev 20:12-13). Faith alone is not at all mentioned there!

Comment: Hebrews 10:1 , Hebrews 7:19  , Acts 13:39 , Roman's  8:3 , John 1:17. To understand what these and many other verses say shows the law is not the way of salvation.  Philippians 3:8-9

Comment: But there is no salvation without the law!! Those who sin “without Law will also PERISH without Law” (Rom 2:12).

Answer (score 0):

Galatians 5:1-4  The law was the fruit of the forbidden tree. Galatians 5:18. If you have the Holy spirit you are not under the law. Do not let law keepers deceive you. Galatians 2:21. Jesus is the tree of life.  If the law could have done what law keepers claim then why a need for a new covenant ?  The old was only a shadow of the new and had no substance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/50549)

Comment: @Lee - If you let the law breakers deceive you, then it is okay to commit adultery, murder etc., in the New Covenant. But the new covenant is to write the law in the hearts and minds (Heb 8:10). Remember, you are “under law” when sin lords it over you (Rom 6:14).

Comment: Gods love is the fulfillment of the law. If you love you will do no harm. Jesus gave two commandments of love to God and neighbor and said no commandment is greater than these, that includes the ten commandments.  Matthew 12:28-34.

Comment: Jesus meant the Ten Commandments by this! The first 4 point to love to God and the latter 6 to neighbor. This is well explained in Romans 13:9 by Paul. So you are right; Ten Commandments cannot be greater than themselves!

Answer (score 0):

Nephesh. I deeply appreciate all of our shared commitment to pleasing the Lord....it is evident in our hearts as we write. It's apparent that everyone in this discussion holds a sincere "God-fearing" desire not to disappoint. The scriptures, illuminated by the teachings of our Savior, Jesus Christ, resonate with profound significance. In reflecting on His words to the righteous law-keepers of His time, particularly the Pharisees, I find His message akin to the depth of the ocean, compelling me to contemplate His simple lesson yet extremely deep.

In quoting Jesus, who addressed the Pharisees as diligent students of the Scriptures, He remarked, "You study the Scriptures diligently because you think that in them you have eternal life. These are the very Scriptures that testify about me." While acknowledging the wealth of knowledge and energy shared in this conversation, I personally view God's word not merely as a source of 'rules' and 'regulations,' but as something far loftier and more profound.

The transformative essence of Christ's purpose is not to convert 'bad' Johnny's into 'good' Johnny's; it is about resurrecting the spiritually 'dead' into the vibrant embrace of life. It is ALL about making 'dead' Johnny's into "living" Johnny's. This transcends the dutiful adherence to laws and rules. True life, in its essence, prioritizes people unconditionally, irrespective of the commandments we might identify as the greatest. Love, expressed through self-sacrifice and enduring relationships, stands as the pivotal force.  As Christ teaching to the Pharisee's...His last words about eternal life   '... Scriptures that testify about me.' The entire bible is about a living relationship with Him.

Our responsibility is to submit our acts of pride and prejudices to Christ, a far more elevated calling and God's desire. This surpasses any mere "keeping" of God's commandments because genuine love goes above and beyond the limits of prescribed commands. It compels us to act abundantly beyond what the commands dictate. This call to love is both convicting and humbling, acknowledging our desperate need for His Spirit to fulfill it, a recognition that echoes a wonderful song that is true in my life: "Lord, I need thee every hour".  I hope my words are encouraging and meaningful.  Forgive me if it is confusing.  Love you all and Blessings my fellow brothers.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/51363)